# How to select columns that have repeating values from another table in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

I am following Zed Shaw's learnSQLthehardway and I wanted to figure out how to select the names from a table person, who owned multiple pets (pets information in table pet.)

```
person_pet Table:    

person_id    pet_id
    0           0
    0           1
    1           1
    1           2
    2           3

person Table:

    id        name
     0         Zed
     1         Orange
     2         Limen


pet Table:

    id        name
     0         Jag
     1         Black
     2         Fluffy
     3         Mister
```

I have been trying to use the COUNT function but I can't seem to get the right results. I must return Zed and Orange based off this data.

```
SELECT name FROM person, person_pet WHERE id = 
(SELECT person_id FROM person_pet GROUP BY person_id HAVING COUNT(person_id) > 1);
```

This is only returning Zed  and not my name. How? What could solve the problem then?

Any help would be great, thank you!

Comment: I can see many problems with this query, starting with an error "subquery returns more than one row".  However, I don't see how it would only return "Zed" and nothing else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `SELECT` from `person` table and `IN` condition from `person_pet` table:

```
SELECT name 
FROM person 
WHERE id IN 
(
    SELECT person_id from person_pet
    GROUP BY person_id
    HAVING COUNT(pet_id) > 1
)
```

Comment: With the exception that it's "id" and not person_id (the first time), thank you!!! IN is what I was missing then. So COUNT basically just returns the number of times a column appears in a table, so it doesn't matter if I got person_id or pet_id

Comment: Updated query to use `id` instead of `person_id`